# Wordpress: Why can't I use is_user_logged_in() after initializing main class on init?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, init

I have a main class for my plugin. It is being instantiated on the `init` action. I thought this would be sufficient to be able to use Wordpress functions like `is_user_logged_in()`, but I'm getting a fatal error: call to undefined function. Below is my code (simplified). **Please see update at the bottom of this question.**

**fd_main.php**

```
<?php
Class Find_Do_For_Anspress{

  private function includes(){
    require_once(FIND_DO_FOR_ANSPRESS_DIR.'fd_echo.php');
  }

}//End class

function find_do_for_anspress() {
    $FDClassStart = new Find_Do_For_AnsPress();

}
add_action('init', 'find_do_for_anspress');

?>
```

**fd_echo.php**

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                echo $current_user;
        } else {
                echo 'Not logged in!';
        }

?>
```

The error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home/effilxhy/public_html/WP/wp-content/plugins/find-do-for-anspress/fd_echo.php on line 1`

---

**Based on answer provided:**

```
//This returns 'exist'. This is outside the main class on the same script.
function test_fn() {
    if ( function_exists('is_user_logged_in') )
        echo 'exists';
    else
        echo 'doesnt exist';
}
add_action('init', 'test_fn');


//This returns 'doesn't exist'. Why doesn't this work?
function test_fn() {
    if ( function_exists('is_user_logged_in') )
        echo 'exists';
    else
        echo 'doesnt exist';
}

test_fn();
```

---

So I think I found something conclusive, but I'm not sure what to make of it. I was defining the function inside the class. I was instantiating the class with `init`, `wp_head`, and `wp_loaded`. I was running `Find_Do_For_Anspress::test_fn();` right after the class definition. This wasn't working. However, when I run Find_Do_For_Anspress::test_fn(); inside one of the included files, it returns "exists", so it works. I tried all of the above action hooks to instantiate my class and they all worked. Why is this? The difference was running the function below my class definition as opposed to running it in an included file.

Comment: PHP fails to locate where `function is_user_logged_in()`, you need to help php finding it and include the file in `fd_echo.php` like `include_once pathTo/theFile.php`

Comment: The problem is that `is_user_logged_in` is a pluggable function, So it's loaded after plugin logic is called. The solution is to make sure that you don't call this too early.

Comment: `init` is too early to run some things. What are you really trying to achieve? What exact moment of your plugin functionality do you need to check if the user is logged or not?

Comment: @brasofilo I am allowing users who are logged in to create a Braintree account through my site (they become "customers"). So I either need to update a custom table with the newly generated Braintree ID or insert a new column into `wp_users` and update that. Any advice on which of these 2 options to go with?

Comment: Well, that's another issue and I think it's better to go first with [`*_user_meta`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=*_user_meta) native functions instead of creating tables. Your `is_user_logged_in` is not working because it's not in the right place and you're showing demo code, not the real situation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried placing the code directly inside the class without using require_once?

Also, I think `require_once` includes the file only the first time the class get created.

--

I don't think the issue is because the function is pluggable. The following code outputs: "exists"

```
function test_fn() {
    if ( function_exists('is_user_logged_in') )
        echo 'exists';
    else
        echo 'doesnt exist';
}
add_action('init', 'test_fn');
```

Comment: I tried defining the function in the main class and then using the function directly underneath the class, but I get the same Call to undefined function error.

Comment: Well, since your code outputs the error when you call the function inside a class, and the code I provided above outputs 'exists' (please verify that in your environment as well) the only assumption left to make is that WordPress somehow initializes classes introduced at 'init' before `is_user_logged_in` is defined. Unless someone comes with an explanation, I'd try using a hook other than 'init' to see if it accomplishes your goals.

Comment: So I think I found something conclusive, if you'd help me reason through it (I'm new to all this). I was defining the function inside the class. I was instantiating the class with `init`, `wp_head`, and `wp_loaded`. I was running `Find_Do_For_Anspress::test_fn();` right after the class definition. This wasn't working. *However*, when I run `Find_Do_For_Anspress::test_fn();` inside one of the included files, it returns "exists". I tried all of the above action hooks to instantiate my class and they all worked. Why is this?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Please post here if you find out.

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows ..

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'check_user_login' );

function check_user_login() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'You are in login state'; 
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry..!';
    }

}
```

Please check [hook list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Comment: The `loop_start` page doesn't exist in the Codex, so I'm hesitant to use this action hook.

Comment: Please try with `wp_head`